# Launching a splash screen activity with deep links

Tags: android

I would like my app to launch a splash screen activity on startup so that I can populate a cache singleton. On normal runs of the application this is trivial as I can set the splash activity as the main launcher activity.

The problem I'm having is how to deal with deep links when the app doesn't happen to be running. In this case the main launcher activity is not invoked and the activity with the appropriate intent filter is launched straight away and the cache is not populated.

Is it possible to intercept the launching intent in the Application class to redirect to the splash activity which would in turn redirect to the original intent?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the cache you are creating shouldn't be living in the Splash Activity as it seems other Activities are dependent on that cache too.

You can make the SplashActivity support all the deeplinks you want and then have logic in the `onCreate` to open the next activity based on the deep link and you can pass the deeplink data to the respective activity by:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.data = this.intent.data
```